# Are humans in Star Wars vegetarian?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Do any *humans* in the Star Wars Galaxy eat meat? In the films at least there are a few scenes of people eating but it only seems to be fruits or veg. Jabba eats a frog type thing and Chewie smells the meat the Ewoks leave out as a trap but no humans seem to eat any non-veggie stuff.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Meat

Comment: Mark Hamill claims that Luke has been vegetarian since Tatooine; https://twitter.com/HamillHimself/status/914245289002680320

Comment: @Valorum does MH speak canon or MH opinion? He seems to say what he thinks LS would/should do. Not a complaint, just saying.

Comment: @Seamusthedog - He's not the arbiter of what his *character* is/does. That's down to Disney. Note also that he's not the only Luke Skywalker actor. There's also Joshua Fardon and Aidan Barton

Comment: Pretty sure Luke and Rey joined Chewbacca for porg-chop dinner.

Comment: I heard that Darth Vader is partial to penne all'arrabbiata, but I can't find a source.

Comment: @NathanCooper https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxX7QCll3oc :-)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Luke

> I accepted, and an afternoon of trading stories about the desert extended into **a dinner of room-service pahzik meat**, which was in my opinion **tastier than nerf** and a significant point in Kupoh’s favor.
>
> <sub><sup>[Heir to the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Heir_to_the_Jedi)</sup></sub>

### Leia

> “I don’t think Ransolm’s starting a trend,” she said drily as she tried to eat her dinner without getting it all over herself. Han had brought back Bilbringi food, **cheesy meat pies with peppers;** she liked Bilbringi, though not quite as much as he did. Tonight, though, it hit the spot. Maybe she shouldn’t be so worried about making messes.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Bloodline](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodline_(novel))</sup></sub>

### Han Solo

> As one, they raced forward. **Han grabbed an entire meat pie in his hands and bit off a huge chunk.** “Ow!” he said around a mouthful. “Sthill thoo hoth!” He kept chewing anyway.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Most Wanted](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Most_Wanted)</sup></sub>

### Jyn Erso

> The soup-soof wasn’t the worst thing she’d ever eaten, but it was close. **She’d take mystery meat from Saw’s cabinet any day** over the oddly textured pillow of squishy saltiness that coated her tongue with a strange, fatty aftertaste.
>
> <sub><sup>[Rebel Rising](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_Rising)</sup></sub>

### Finn

> “Makes sense.” FN-2187 used the corner of a chunk of mealbread to wipe up the last of the cream on his plate. The meal, like so many others, hadn’t been designed for flavor as much as efficiency—**slivers of overcooked meat in a numian sauce** that tasted more like chalk than anything else. But it was filling and provided energy, and that was the point.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Before the Awakening](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Before_the_Awakening)</sup></sub>

### Rey

> First thing in the morning, Rey broke the seal on one of the quick-meals and ate, what was to her, some of the finest food she’d ever enjoyed. She had no idea what it was, but **there was actual meat product and a sauce that was sweet and tangy at the same time** and something she thought might be nuts, which popped between her teeth with a satisfying snap.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Before the Awakening](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Before_the_Awakening)</sup></sub>

### Tarkin

> **His hunger partially staved by dried meat almost too tough to swallow**,
>   Wilhuff was beginning to have serious misgivings, though he refused to
>   let them be known.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))</sup></sub>

### Chirrut and Baze

> Chirrut just shook his head. Baze went quiet, finished preparing their meal, then set the bowl down in front of Chirrut before sitting heavily opposite him to dig into his own. Chirrut ate, chewing slowly. **It was a noodle stew, with cut-up chunks of one of the many species of worms that lived in the sands,** for added protein.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Guardians of the Whills](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Whills)</sup></sub>

---

To find instances of the Jedi/Sith eating meat we have to delve into the weird and wacky "Legends"

### Palpatine

> “You appear to be enjoying the steak, Ambassador Palpatine.”
>   “Exquisite,” he said, holding her gaze for a fraction longer than might have been called for.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis_(novel))</sup></sub>

### Anakin

Comment: so only in novel/comic and not in film? Meat pie, must be from the north of the Galaxy!

Comment: @Seamusthedog - These are all from various canon novels. I haven't looked at the films yet

Comment: Hmm. I'd like to add Anakin and Obi-Wan to my collection

Comment: Slimy, yet satisfying; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jA9ksYF1ZRs

Comment: I recall Luke asking for "banta steak" in one of the old (RotJ-time) comics.

Comment: Cribbing lines from Disney, that's the way it's going to go!

Comment: "slivers of overcooked meat in a numian sauce" So even a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away, they ate chipped beef?

Comment: @JAB - A friend of mine wasn't happy about his mess ration and asked his CSM if there was a complaints procedure. The response was that he was welcome to write to the MOD at '123 Shut Up and Eat It Street.'

Comment: @Seamusthedog I guess it's because the answerer just searched for the word "meat" in the books, which is quick and easy to do; it is more difficult to scan the movies if you don't remember a specific scene (although having a transcript helps).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - Searching is easy. Collecting and assembling every single canon novel source into one place is rather harder. Then identifying (from the hundreds of possible matches) which apply to *each of the major characters* is rather harder still.

Comment: @Seamusthedog If you wanted to limit the sources to the films, you should have specified that in the question.

Comment: @AJFaraday I didn't say only film.

Comment: The Jyn Erso quote doesn't actually say that she eats meat; it just says that she'd prefer meat to what she's eating now. I mean, I could say "I'd rather drink piss than [insert name of beer you don't like here]." That doesn't mean I actually drink urine; it just means I really don't want to drink that beer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - There are several mentions of her eating food from his supply cabinet earlier in the books. She also eats "stew" a little later on, although it's not mentioned what kind of stew.

Answer (score 44):

Luke SkyWalker kills a large fish in *The Last Jedi*, presumably for dinner.

Comment: A considerable number of "vegetarians" eat fish; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pescetarianism

Comment: @Valorum I believe a considerable number of **pescetarians** eat fish

Comment: Anyone got any Mon Calamari jokes?

Comment: @user20310 - I would imagine they all do. But some of them consider themselves to be vegetarians.

Comment: @Valorum I'm vegetarian. I only eat things that grow out of the dirt like carrots and fish.

Comment: @Valorum I think possibly that was a definition of "vegetarian" many years ago and might still exist in some places, but at least in the modern US I don't think you'll find anyone who self-identifies as vegetarian who eats any kind of flesh. (It was kind of a joke in the '80s and '90s that people in the Midwest would try to serve fish to vegetarians when they came to visit, possibly modeled on the Catholic-fasting definition of "meat", but I think that's pretty rare today.)

Comment: @Valorum There's a difference between Pescetarianism and Vegetarianism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism `Vegetarianism is the practice of abstaining from the consumption of meat (red meat, poultry, **seafood**, and the flesh of any other animal)..`

Comment: thanks for the good answer, new user!

Comment: I'm with Valorum, plenty of veggies (self described) eat fish, they wear leather shoes and jackets and for no religious reason won't eat red meat. Maybe depends what side of the Atlantic you are on....

Comment: @1006a: I’ve been vegetarian all my life (not eating fish), and lived in the UK, the US, and several European countries.  Definitions of vegetarianism vary between places, times, and individuals; it’s more standard now in the UK and US that “vegetarian” excludes fish, but there are still a few “vegetarians” that eat fish, and many more non-vegetarians who think of vegetarianism as including fish. And there are large parts of the world where “vegetarianism” is understood to exclude eggs too, for instance.  Culture is complicated; our definition isn’t the only correct one.

Comment: I hadn't considered fish when I asked the question. I'll eat most things classed as food but don't have an opinion on the definition of vegetarian etc. It's all personal. As I don't know much about canon and legends the good users of this site keep me right (and knock down my stupidity)

Comment: Problem is that if you include extraterestial stuff in the list. So what exactly makes for fish in a galactic context?

Comment: The big giant fish type thing on the end of Luke's spear in the video above?

Comment: @1006a Not so rare as you might hope. My grandmother tried this "everyone else I know who's vegetarian also eats fish and chicken!" after she put chicken broth in the rice... And she's well educated and otherwise up to date on current affairs....

Comment: @Valorum The OP provides the definition they want to go by.  For this question, 'meat' is "non-veggie stuff".  It's probably safe to conclude that fish, even alien fish, is non-veggie stuff (and therefore, 'meat').  What some humans who self-identify as vegetarian happen to eat in this galaxy is mostly neither here nor there.

Comment: @aroth again what does plant mean in galactic context. Its an arbitrary definition that works on earth but what happens if you have a animal like thing that descended from "plants" somewhere. The distinction is way too diffuse in a galactic context.

Comment: @Seamusthedog The fact that some people misuse the term and make it almost useless for the rest of us shouldn’t mean we give it up as a lost cause. Plenty of people eat just about anything and still call themselves ‘vegetarians’ (a former acquaintance of mine self-identified as vegetarian because he only eats red meat if minced, for example); that doesn’t really get anyone anywhere. The only definition of vegetarianism with any hope of authority is that given by the International Vegetarian Union, which excludes all types of meat, including fish.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not arguing the correct meaning of being a veggie.  i am only asking a question I thought was a bit of fun, not turn into a bloated debate abut the definition of vegetarianism.

Answer (score 11):

In *Empire Strikes Back*, I always thought that Yoda was eating some kind of meat that Luke brought with him to Dagobah. Luke had a box of food, and Yoda stole what looks like a sausage or a fish stick.
Here's a clip, see around timestamp 1:22 for Yoda eating the food.

Comment: Wow, nice spot! Certainly could be some sort of processed meat treat.

Comment: Luke's tray seems to contain some meatballs or brown eggs... But if Yoda did not mind eating up anything resembling food (in this case, just for his amusement) indicates that he did not mind to eat meat by chance.

Comment: It's described as a "protein stick" in the canon novelisation; (*The creature sits down and with a satisfied grin takes a bite of the protein stick*)"

Comment: There's no indication that his tray contains any meat products, btw. All it says in the novels is "processed foods" and "pre-packed rations". You might want to note that in real life it was a spray-painted pretzel stick since anything moist would have stained the puppet.

Comment: I always assumed it was a granola bar or similar.

Answer (score 1):

When I read this question, a quote from ESB of Princess Leia Organa to Han Solo comes to my mind:

> "Why, you low-down, stuck-up, half-witted, scruffy-looking nerf-herder…"

So, the nerfs are animals for meat production. I'm pretty sure I read about them first in the Republic Commando books, maybe somebody can quote something about nerfs. To come back to my main point, even in Star Wars there exists a mass production of meat, with nerf herders on different planets.

Comment: The quote was fine, I just tidied it up so it reads "nicer" and of course removed the bit about asking for clarification on formatting. In future you can put those comments in the comments to your answer and I'm sure someone would see them.

Comment: Back to the answer though, maybe you could find some quote about nerfs being used for meat production to back this up?

Comment: I could search the books, but that would be time consuming. Do you know if there is a database in which I could search for references, or are all the guys here really searching in movies and books?

Comment: Not that I know of, a lot of people probably have the eBooks and scripts/transcripts somewhere where they can search them easily. I know I mostly just search somewhere if I know there's something similar to what I want in a certain book/film.

Comment: Too bad. I read a lot, but I like real books, so I don't have access to the information all the time.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - In the original film, I don't think that it was described what a nerf is, other than something that can be herded.

Comment: @Valorum you're right, but at the moment, I don't have access to my books for the references.

Comment: @Valorum in the book "Order 66- A Republic Commando Novel", a few characters are eating at the "Haunch of Nerf". It is mentioned in the german novel at page 86.

Comment: @Hyperion - My first quote (from the canon novel 'Heir to the Jedi') mentions the eating of Nerf

Comment: @Hyperion - There are innumerable canon references to nerf steak, nerf stew, nerf cutlets, etc

Comment: @Valorum Yes, I have seen the references many times. But I don't have books here to actually prove it.

Comment: @Hyperion - You could ask it as a main site question... "*How many ways are there to eat Nerf?"*